# Retrieve user's medias and the likes on those medias - What permission is needed? Will i go live?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

If I want to access medias of users I follow, and read the likes on those medias, what permission do I need? And would I be granted permission to go live if I use my app as an individual?

Comment: approval depends on what your app does, which usecase does is solve, add details about that. you will need, `basic`, `likes` , `public_content` permissions

Comment: @krisrak I would use the app to search content liked by a given user, but in the "Login permission" section on the Instagram API docs it says that I need to be a brand or an advertiser that wants to understand their user base preferences. Here is the page: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/. Are those use cases just examples?

Comment: u will get API approval for creating platform or service, not for one off individual project, you can build and try for approval... (btw you can search liked posts using picodash.com - my app)